# Error detaching volume : Volume is in the 'available' state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, volume, detach, umount

I want to detach volume from ec2-instance in aws but getting following error :

```
Error detaching volume : Volume is in the 'available' state.
```

I Have unmounted that disk ie fdisk -l doesn't show that volume also I have tried "Force Detach Volume" option. Still getting above error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You appear to be getting an error because the volume is *already* `available` -- which means it is not attached to any instance at this point.

If it were still attached, its state would be `in-use`... or `detaching` if it were attached with a detach request still in progress but not yet complete.

If you're looking at the console and it still shows one of those states, the console may be showing a stale state and need refreshing.

Comment: But it was showing "Attachment information
i-9dbd0219 (ADM-DEL-CERT-STAGING-HIPHOP-NEW):/dev/xvdz (atached)" in aws-console so I tried force detach

Comment: So I stopped that instance and then it was able to detach so can we detach volume from live instance ?